# Is it possible to have image resizer replace our existing different sized image folder structure?

Tags: imageresizer

Our current image folder structure consists of the same image at different sizes for use within our website

Content/thumb/5316.jpg

Content/ShotView/5316.jpg

Content/miniview/5316.jpg

Content/Full/5316.jpg

Is it possible to have imageresizer handle/rewrite the requests to the smaller size images as calls to the Full image with default height/width parameters depending on the folder selected can I do this via a combination of IIS virtual directories and default settings?

So we could retain our existing structure but as products change we would only need the 1 original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need is some URL rewriting; no need for Virtual Directories.

The `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite` even will let you parse and edit the path and querystring in code, which is the most flexible solution.

[IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), however, is also capable of solving your problem.